# Enumeration yielded no results for PowerShell Invoke

Tags: c#, powershell, office365

I am executing PowerShell command in C# code. The code adds a email address distribution list in O365. PowerShell is able to add the user to distribution list but it also giving exception too. Why?

```
        using (powershell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            command = new PSCommand();
            command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
            string DLGroupName = "UnsubscribersList";
            command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock",
                System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Create(
                    "Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity '" + DLGroupName + "' -Member " + txtEmail.Text + ""));
            command.AddParameter("Session", session);
            powershell.Commands = command;
            powershell.Runspace = runspace;
            result = powershell.Invoke();
            if (powershell.Streams.Error.Count > 0 || result.Count != 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Fail to establish the connection");
            }
        }
```

Errors:

> powershell.Streams.Error is throwing
>   Enumeration yielded no results
>   result.Count is 0

Answer (score 0):

Result will always be **0**.

When you run PowerShell it will execute the script and return the **exit code 0** to tell you that **PowerShell.exe** successfully ran **no matter what *actually* happens inside your script**.

If you want results to propagate outside the "PowerShell.exe" instance, you have to either have a command in the script to explicitly exit with a known exit code (exit code 0 typically signals success), or save the result to the HDD/SQL/or somewhere else that can be read.